# Не знаю, как реализовать кодировку и декодировку QR-кодов в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, qrcode

Хочу понять эту тему на простом примере:

1. Я ввожу текст и, соответсвенно, он преобразуется в QrCode.
2. Загружая jpg(или любой другой формат) картинку с Qr-кодом, получаю зашифрованную информацию.

---

Полный текст ошибки:

```
    C:\Users\User>pip install git+https://github.com/ewino/qreader.git
Collecting git+https://github.com/ewino/qreader.git
  Cloning https://github.com/ewino/qreader.git to c:\users\user\appdata\local\te
mp\pip-req-build-oc3frfw6
  Error [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл while executing command git
 clone -q https://github.com/ewino/qreader.git C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\
pip-req-build-oc3frfw6
Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [Генерация](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2d33b231029b8e2ab1bb81da072b6163860c5a2f/qrcode__generate/main.py) QR-code. Используя [qrcode](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode):

   ```
   text = 'Hello World!'

   # pip install qrcode
   import qrcode
   img = qrcode.make(text)

   # In file
   img.save('qr_code_1.png')
   ```

   Результат:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. [Чтение](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/cdb2dbaa8aa7d20e194ba47f76cdb5889cc277c3/qrcode__reader/main.py) QR-code. Используя [qreader](https://github.com/ewino/qreader):

   ```
   # pip install git+https://github.com/ewino/qreader.git
   import qreader

   # QR-код из пункта 1.
   url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4KD6.png'
   from urllib.request import urlopen
   data = qreader.read(urlopen(url))
   print(data)  # "Hello World!"
   ```

   Если нужно из файла, то передаем путь к нему или файловый объект:

   ```
   data = qreader.read('../qrcode__generate/qr_code_1.png')
   print(data)  # Hello World!
   ```

---

**PS.**

Возможно, для `qreader` нужно будет `reedsolo` устанавливать (`pip install reedsolo`)

**PPS.**

Для выполнения `pip install git+https://github.com/ewino/qreader.git` инсталятор `pip` будет работать через `git`, поэтому нужно чтобы он [стоял в системе](https://git-scm.com/)

Comment: Не получилось установить модуль qreader(пользовался pip install reedsolo), а первый способ - не понял.

Comment: @Arhansolo, вы ввели в консоль `pip install git+https://github.com/ewino/qreader.git` и какие ошибки были? Первый способ в пункте 2?

Comment: Win Error 2: Не удаётся найти указанный файл while executing command

Comment: @Arhansolo, нужен весь текст ошибки. То, что вы привели это явно только часть. Добавьте в pastebin и ссылку сюда -- нужен весь текст из консоли, а точнее команду `pip install git+https://github.com/ewino/qreader.git` и ошибку

Comment: Я добавил полный текст ошибки в вопрос

Comment: @Arhansolo, смотрите, в ошибке есть все :) `Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?` т.е. установщику нужен `git`, который будет описан в переменных средах в PATH. Установите git (https://git-scm.com/) после установки закройте и откройте консоль (чтобы информация о текущих переменных средах актуализировалась для текущей консоли) и введите `git`. Если запустилось, все ок. После напишите тот импорт. Инфу насчет гит добавлю в ответ

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: @Arhansolo, пожалуйста :)