# Как создать qr код из сообщения пользователя и отправить его пользователю в telebot

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, qrcode

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу написать так называемый генератор qr кодов в telegram

Comment: Ответ на втором сайте в гугле - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922491/Не-знаю-как-реализовать-кодировку-и-декодировку-qr-кодов-в-python Текст пользователя `message.text` передаете в метод `qrcode.make(message.text)`. Сгенерированную фотографию отправляете пользователю методом `bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('qr.png', 'rb'))`

Answer (score 1):

Вот один из примеров реализации вашей задачи:

`#pip install qrcode`

```
import telebot 
import qrcode

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def generate(message):
    img = qrcode.make(message.text)
    img.save('qr_code.png')
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('qr_code.png', 'rb'))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: @mixergame, пожалуйста) Исправил в коде небольшую опечатку